# Como puedo retornar el valor de un metodo que esta dentro de otro metodo

Tags: java, android

estoy haciendo una petición con `Okhttp` y en el método `onResponse()` estoy almacenando en la variable `myResponse` el resultado de dicha petición, mi pregunta es, como puedo hacer que el método `peticion()` retorne le valor de la variable `myResponse`, agradecería ejemplo de código puesto que aún no soy muy bueno programando, gracias de antemano

```
 public String peticion(){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();


            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                       String myResponse = response.body().string();

                    }
                }
             });
        return
    }
```

Comment: Si lo que quieres es devolver myResponse, ¿has probado a declararlo debajo de la declaración de client? Así podrás hacer return myResponse. Eso si, cuando lo declares le tenrás que dar un valor, "" por ejemplo.

Comment: Creo que también método en response debería de ser `public String onResponse( . . .)` y que en el return tenga response.

Comment: Mira la respuesta de @DAvid, tiene razón.Al al hacerlo en un hilo, tendrás que utilizar un EventHandler para poder obtener el resultado una vez finalice la ejecución del hilo y enviarlo al hilo principal.

Comment: si quisieras que `peticion()` fuese sincrono y espere la respuesta para retornarla, tendrias que utilizar `client.newCall(request).execute(...)` en lugar de `enqueue`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Después de la llamada al método petición, si retornas inmediatamente el valor `responsePeticion` es normal que este sea "".
Ten en cuenta que estás dentro de una *CallBack* y que el método *onResponse* se ejecutará de manera asíncrona por parte del servidor cuando genere la respuesta.

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una clase para gestionar el *onResponse* del *CallBack*.

Una clase, que se llame por ejemplo EventHandler, y que tenga un método String `responseReceived(String response)` que se llamado desde dentro del `onResponse` del `CallBack`.

Algo así:

```
public void peticion(EventHandler eventHandler){
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String responsePeticion = "";

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();


        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                responsePeticion = "Error in request";
                Log.e("Error", "Request error", e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                   eventHandler.responseReceived(response.body().string())

                }
            }
         });
}
```

La clase EventHandler en prinpio debería ser muy sencilla.